# Store Python tree in memory and access it frequently

Tags: python, memory, process

I have a ternary search tree written in Python loaded with around 200K valid English words. I am using it for dictionary look-up, as I am writing a Boggle-like app which accesses the tree very frequently to judge whether a sequence of letters is a valid word.

Right now my app is just a script that you call from the CLI. However, I'm architecting my app as a client-server model. Since it takes quite some time to load all the words into the tree, I don't want to do that for every request made to the server. Ideally, the tree should persist as an in-memory object in the server, receiving requests and sending responses.

I have tried Pyro4 but the overhead of network I/O grows larger as the frequency of access increases. So it's not a viable option with diminishing rate of returns. I wish to implement a lower-level solution with lesser I/O overhead. I have read up about shared memory and server process (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) but I'm not sure how to adapt them to non-primitive Python objects such as my ternary search tree. This is my first time doing this sort of thing, so I'd appreciate it if you guys can give some guidance.

Comment: What questions does your tree answer? Just whether a word is in there, or also something else (like whether it's a prefix of a word in there)?

Comment: Both actually, and they return true/false.

Comment: Here's the code for the tree: https://github.com/uohzxela/wordbase-solver/blob/master/src/tst.py

Comment: Thanks, I played around with that and also tested an alternative solution that simply uses a set of the words and a set of their prefixes. You can see it [here](https://gist.github.com/pochmann/adcd1e046c62390fd61b). On top there are results of speed and correctness tests. My alternative solution is in lines 118-122. I also checked the memory consumption, building your tree took about 49 MB, building my sets took about 86 MB. So mine uses more memory, but is faster and simpler and uses only Python types (set and str).

Comment: I changed it now so the full words aren't stored as prefixes as well, now it takes 76 MB instead of 86 MB. Speed remained about the same. Sorry I can't directly help with your question / described plan, btw.

Comment: Hey it's alright! That's a really interesting experiment and observation. I appreciate the effort and having a much simpler and faster solution really opens more opportunities to store the object in memory, or nullify the need for in-memory storage altogether. I will adapt your solution to my app and see if it's a good fit. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, was interesting for me as well. I updated again, added another tree solution, where the tree is just nested dictionaries. It's even faster to build and for invalid words (see the updated results, top of the file) and took about 77 MB.

Comment: I think, with your solution, it's fast enough to forgo the in-memory storage. Will use your TreeJudge solution in my web app for now. Thanks again!

Comment: What web framework are you using that requires you to rebuild the tree on every request? Can you not simply load it as a module global or app global somewhere and keep it in memory like that.